# an Error in my php code about curl and send json with post method

Tags: php, json, curl

an Error in my php code about curl and send json with post method 
this is my send.php code :

```
$url = "http://localhost/get.php";    
$data = array(
    'item1'      => 'value1',
    'item2'      => 'value2',
    'item3'       => 'value3'
);


$content = json_encode($data);

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
        array("Content-type: application/json"));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);

$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ( $status != 201 ) {
    die("Error: call to URL $url failed with status $status, response $json_response, curl_error " . curl_error($curl) . ", curl_errno " . curl_errno($curl));
}


curl_close($curl);

$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
```

and this my get.php code :

```
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
  $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
  print_r($data);
}
```

then show this Error to me :

```
Error: call to URL http://localhost/get.php failed with status 200, response stdClass Object ( [item1] => value1 [item2] => value2 [item3] => value3 ) , curl_error , curl_errno 0
```

what to do guys ?

Comment: what do you expect? You got an http 200 response from the url you hit, and your code only wants 201. That's not something we can help with. You're the one generating a `200 ok` with the php code.

Comment: 200 is a valid response, it means OK. https://httpstatuses.com/200

Comment: @MarcB i want send that json with post and show it for my first  time training

Comment: @aynber yes 200 is Ok but it returns 201

Comment: Well, your code can't produce that error anyways. curl_exec either returns a string, or a boolean false. it will NOT respond with a stdclass object, and PHP can't time travel either. you decode the json later on, but at the point you spit out that error you've still only got TEXT.

Comment: uh, no. nothing returned a 201. Your curl response came back with a 200, but then you reject it because it's NOT a 201.

Comment: @aynber  Oooops  , you are right . it returns  200 . but why it did not echo my json ?

Comment: how can i echo response of get.php